# OpenTelemetry Spring Boot Reactive incorrect spans

Tags: spring, spring-boot, open-telemetry, micrometer-tracing, open-telemetry-java

I am in the process of integrating OTEL traces/metrics/logs into our application stack. For the most part this process has been going good, with the exception of a few hiccups along the way which -- fortunately -- have been resolved. Currently our set of applications uses both blocking and reactive implementations, meaning that I need to integrate OTEL to instrument both.

For the case of the blocking apps, everything seems to be going smoothly and I have been able to create useful spans using the various instrumentation libraries like Mongo, WebMvc etc. This results in the following spans to be created:

[image]

As you can see the drilldown is quite nice and everything gets captured correctly.

However when I attempt to do the same for a non-blocking/reactive application I am getting inconsistent spans. For instance check the following:

[image]

As you can see the three spans:

1. journey find sis.journeys
2. journey POST /journeys
3. journey http post /journeys

should have been one single span with no3 being the parent and 2 and 1 being child spans. I have tried to debug this and figure out what the problem really is but I am a bit lost. As far as I can tell I am not doing anything special in contrast to the blocking app, other than attempting to instrument a reactive app in this case.

Library wise I have added the following in place:

```
    runtimeOnly 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-otlp:1.12.1'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel:1.2.1'

    implementation 'io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-logging'
    implementation 'io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-otlp'
    runtimeOnly 'io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-common'
    implementation 'io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-logback-appender-1.0'
    implementation 'io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-resources'
    implementation 'io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-mongo-3.1'
    implementation 'io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-spring-web-3.1'
    implementation 'io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-spring-webflux-5.3'
    implementation 'io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-instrumentation-annotations'
```

and as you can see I am bridging OTEL with micrometer. Based on all the above my questions are the following:

1. How can I resolve the issue of properly instrumenting a reactive application and end up producing correct spans
2. In both cases there is a span created by a library named `org.springframework.boot`. This is seemingly a duplicate span having the same information as the one captured by either the webmvc instrumentation library or the webflux instrumentation library. While not a problem, is there a way to disable this and what really produces this?

Edit: Adding result after swapping out of libraries

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any error in our dependencies, so I would file this as a bug with spring-boot (which may end up in micrometer, that's a bit hard to know).

In the meantime, you can try out another spring starter, which uses different libraries, so it may not be affected by the bug: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/java/automatic/spring-boot/

Note that this starter is not compatible with the starter from spring boot - configuration and produced telemetry differs.

Comment: I gave the starter a go and the problem still persists (look at the screenshot attached in the original question). Still when using reactive, I am getting Spans that are out of place. Those three spans should have been child spans instead, not individual ones.

Comment: So I am inclined to believe that the problem lies with the way spans are created when in Reactive mode.

Comment: Reactive is more difficult to get right, so it's a bug in both projects - and an issue would be highly welcome.

Comment: Yeap I will create one then but would i be possible to point me towards the appropriate project/projects?

Comment: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot

Comment: Please try to migrate to Boot 3.2.x and reactor 3.6.x. Also, please do not define version on your own and let the Boot BOM define them for you. Also, if you want to use Micrometer Tracing, Spring is already instrumented, try not do define io.opentelemetry dependencies first.